# MessageDialog unresponsive after FileDialog ShowModal

Tags: python, wxpython

Hey guys I've been trying to debug this issue for a while to no avail.

I've defined a function bound to a button that calls up a FileDialog, if the user clicks OK, the function resumes. Immediately after ID_OK I attempted to call a simple dialog prompting the user to select files from another directory. Immediately after this message dialog appears, there appears to be a delay where the user can't press OK or CANCEL on the first click. It takes repeated clicking for the buttons to respond. If anybody has any idea what's going on here or what can be done to debug this issue I will be very grateful :). I've attached the snippet of code (albeit with a SingleChoiceDialog though the behavior is the same as with MessageDialog). For the record dlg is destroyed after the conditional statement.

```
def openFile(self, event):
    import os
    import re
    import csv
    import sets
    import datetime

    dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose file(s)", os.getcwd(), "", "*.*", wx.OPEN | wx.MULTIPLE | wx.CHANGE_DIR)

    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        path = dlg.GetPaths()

        test = wx.SingleChoiceDialog(self, 'Add more files from different directories?', 'Selected Files', path, style=wx.CHOICEDLG_STYLE)

        while test.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            dlgAdd = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose file(s)", os.getcwd(), "", "*.*", wx.OPEN | wx.MULTIPLE | wx.CHANGE_DIR)
            if dlgAdd.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
                break
            dlgAdd.Destroy()
            path = path + dlgAdd.GetPaths()
            test = wx.SingleChoiceDialog(self, 'Add more files from different directories?', 'Selected Files', path, style=wx.CHOICEDLG_STYLE)

        test.Destroy()
```

Was digging around some more online and found reports of similar issues: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.wxpython/55470. It does seem to be an issue with passing focus though none of them offered fixes or workarounds however.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an "if" instead of a "while" for the "test" dialog. I suspect you have an infinite or near-infinite loop thing going on whenever they press the OK button. If the user presses CANCEL on the dlgAdd dialog, your program never destroys dlgAdd since it breaks out of the loop at that point. That's also an issue and probably why the "test" dialog is hung for a while.

Comment: Hmmm even if I remove the while loop altogether and just add if dlgAdd.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK: to start the function (granted this simplification is not the desired functionality), the issue still persists.

Comment: Unresponsiveness might not be the best word to describe the issue actually. It's interesting I can wait 1 second or 10 seconds after the dialog pops up and first click on either the OK or CANCEL button, resize, move, ETC all fail. It's almost as if it's a problem with focus since I can touch any part of the dialog after it pops up and then the OK and CANCEL buttons instantly work.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh okay figured it out the error stems from the use of Coherence mode when using Parallels. After turning this off the dialogs worked perfectly.